# Class within class using prototype OOP

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have the follow code:

```
function A(){
    this.init.apply( this, arguments );
}

A.prototype = {

    name: "",

    init: function( nameOfSomething ){

        this.name = nameOfSomething;

    }

};
```

In this way i can use:

```
var something = new A();
```

And i want to add another class in the "A" class. Like B.

I want to use:

```
something.B = new B();

something.B.name = "testing";
```

B having any propertys and methods i want!

Someone?

Comment: What's your question? Is your code not working for you? Are you getting some error?

Comment: You have no B function defined

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "extend" an object of "class" A (and javascript does not have classes and you will get burned if act as if it does), do [untested]:

```
function B () {}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.init("bla");

var b = new B();
b.name; /* should return "bla" */
```

But I'm fairly sure that this does not in fact do what you want/expect. See http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html for my attempt at explaining the general mechanism and its pitfalls.